# nuget returning packages with nuget-feed's index.json in body instead of content

Tags: nuget, paket

I'm using `paket restore` to download a large number of nuget packages from the `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` feed.

After downloading some packages successfully, it reports a `InvalidDataException: End of Central Directory record could not be found.` on a package (different each time).

When I look inside the package in the Nuget cache (Windows 10), it contains the json from the index of the feed at `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`, rather than expected content.

For example, for `System.Net.Http 4.3.4.nupkg` opening the file in Notepad shows the contents as:

```json
{
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-usnc.nuget.org/query",
      "@type": "SearchQueryService",
      "comment": "Query endpoint of NuGet Search service (primary)"
    },
    {
      "@id": "https://azuresearch-ussc.nuget.org/query",
      "@type": "SearchQueryService",
      "comment": "Query endpoint of NuGet Search service (secondary)"
    },
// etc
```

So it looks like the request is somehow being redirected to the root of the feed.

Any ideas on what could be causing this, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a fix, but not a reason why!

I had been clearing my Nuget cache after each error with

- `nuget locals all -clear`

That didn't help.  I then tried

- `paket clear-cache`

And then my `paket restore` worked fine.